# Match entre dictonary e array

Tags: python, regex

**OBJETIVO:**

Estou tentando fazer um match entre um **dictonary** e um **array**. Eu quero verificar se o conteúdo do array está contido no `KEY NAME` do dictonary, se estiver ele deve me retornar a linha inteira do dictonary.

```
import re

dict = {
    "NAME": "LUIS", "AGE": "25", "CITY": "SAO PAULO", 
    "NAME": "LUCAS", "AGE": "30", "CITY": "SANTA CATARINA", 
    "NAME": "CARLOS", "AGE": "35", "CITY": "BAHIA"
}

array = ["LUCAS","LUIS"]

matches = []
for row in range(len(dict)):
    pattern = re.compile(r'^'+dict["NAME"][row]+'$')
    matches.append([x for x in array if pattern.match(x)])

for linha in matches:
    print(linha)
```

**OUTPUT**

> C:\Users\Luis\Desktop>python regex.py
>
> []

Comment: O jeito no qual seu dicionario esta sendo utilizado esta errado, primeiramente não utilize o nome da variável como _dicit_ essa palavra faz parte do python, ou seja, uma keyword reservada. Outra coisa, a maneira que seu dicionario esta estruturado faz com que exista somente uma linha nele. Se tu der um print nele a saída sera: `{'CITY': 'BAHIA', 'NAME': 'CARLOS', 'AGE': '35'}`

Comment: Certo, se o dictionary estiver correto, como deve ser a busca ?

Comment: A busca esta certa. Unica coisa que faria seria transformar para lower case para evitar problemas (A não ser que não possa), e depois transformaria em um array (lista em python),dessa forma cada item seria um dicionario

Comment: Me parece mais um caso de [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy). Foi mencionado que os dados do dicionário vieram de um banco de dados, portanto este filtro deveria ser feito na query usando uma cláusula `WHERE`... Exemplo: `WHERE NAME LIKE "%LUCAS%" OR NAME LIKE "%LUIS%"`

Comment: Precisa ser processado em back-end os dados, são muitos elementos dentro do array, a resposta do @hkotsubo resolveu o problema, obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente, seu dicionário está errado, pois ele repete as mesmas chaves, sobrescrevendo os valores anteriores, então na verdade ele só tem isso:

```
{'NAME': 'CARLOS', 'AGE': '35', 'CITY': 'BAHIA'}
```

**Talvez** o que você queira é uma lista contendo 3 dicionários:

```
dados = [
    { "NAME": "LUIS", "AGE": "25", "CITY": "SAO PAULO" }, 
    { "NAME": "LUCAS", "AGE": "30", "CITY": "SANTA CATARINA" }, 
    { "NAME": "CARLOS", "AGE": "35", "CITY": "BAHIA" }
]
```

Agora sim podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
import re

dados = [
    { "NAME": "LUIS", "AGE": "25", "CITY": "SAO PAULO" }, 
    { "NAME": "LUCAS", "AGE": "30", "CITY": "SANTA CATARINA" }, 
    { "NAME": "CARLOS", "AGE": "35", "CITY": "BAHIA" }
]

array = ["LUCAS", "LUIS"]

matches = []
for linha in dados:
    pattern = re.compile('^{}$'.format(linha["NAME"]))
    if any(x for x in array if pattern.match(x)):
        matches.append(linha)

for linha in matches:
    print(linha)
```

Para cada dicionário, eu verifico se existe algum elemento do `array` que corresponde ao `NAME` deste dicionário (usando a [função `any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), que retorna `True` caso exista algum elemento que satisfaça o critério).

A saída é:

```
{'NAME': 'LUIS', 'AGE': '25', 'CITY': 'SAO PAULO'}
{'NAME': 'LUCAS', 'AGE': '30', 'CITY': 'SANTA CATARINA'}
```

---

Se quiser que a busca seja *case insensitive* (ou seja, que não diferencie maiúsculas e minúsculas, assim o `array` poderia ter `'luis'` que a busca também encontraria), basta usar a [*flag* `IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) ao criar a regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('^{}$'.format(linha["NAME"]), re.IGNORECASE)
```

---

Lembrando que a sua regex usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Ou seja, se o nome contido no dicionário for "LUIS", a regex será `^LUIS$`: isso quer dizer que ela busca exatamente pela string "LUIS". Se quiser buscar por algo que **contenha** a string "LUIS", mas que possa ter outros caracteres antes ou depois, basta remover o `^` e o `$`.

---

Para o caso que você [informou nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/407216/match-entre-dictonary-e-array/407230#comment796911_407230) (no dicionário tem "LUIS01" e no array tem "LUIS"), aí é o contrário: o que tem no array que deve ser usado na regex, e você deve verificar se ela encontra um *match* no conteúdo do dicionário:

```
import re

dados = [
    { "NAME": "LUIS01", "AGE": "25", "CITY": "SAO PAULO" }, 
    { "NAME": "LUCAS", "AGE": "30", "CITY": "SANTA CATARINA" }, 
    { "NAME": "CARLOS", "AGE": "35", "CITY": "BAHIA" }
]
array = ["LUCAS", "LUIS"]
matches = []
for linha in dados:
    if any(x for x in array if re.match(x, linha['NAME'], re.IGNORECASE)):
        matches.append(linha)

for linha in matches:
    print(linha)
```

Saída:

```
{'NAME': 'LUIS01', 'AGE': '25', 'CITY': 'SAO PAULO'}
{'NAME': 'LUCAS', 'AGE': '30', 'CITY': 'SANTA CATARINA'}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso amigo, pois o dicionário é formado por um select ao banco de dados DB2, me ajudou muito, obrigado!

Comment: Só uma dúvida se no caso, os nomes contidos dentro da KEY NAME, fossem diferentes, por exemplo dict = LUIS01  e array = Luis, como ficaria essa parte pattern = re.compile('^{}$'.format(linha["NAME"])) ?

Comment: @LuisV. Atualizei a resposta (com base no que eu entendi, veja se é isso mesmo)

Comment: testei dessa forma: 'pattern = re.compile('{}'.format(linha["NAME"]), re.IGNORECASE)', mas não me retornou nada, sabe qual o problema ?

Comment: @LuisV. Agora acho que entendi, atualizei a resposta de novo

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente essa dúvida, muito obrigado!

Comment: Se o dicionário vem do banco de dados, porque você está filtrando no python ao invés de adicionar uma  cláusula `WHERE ` na sua query?

Comment: Precisa ser processado em back-end os dados, são muitos elementos dentro do array, a resposta do @hkotsubo resolveu o problema, obrigado!